# How Do I Compute FSEventStreamEventFlags?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, objective-c++, fsevents

On OSX, I'm using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36469891/105539) to detect new files dragged, dropped, and created in a folder path (or subpath).

However, the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/FSEventStreamEventFlags) doesn't include any information on how to compute the value of FSEventStreamEventFlags.

So, through trial and error, I'm having to make an array like so:

```
const unsigned short TOTAL_EVENTS = 9;
unsigned int anEvents[TOTAL_EVENTS];
anEvents[0] = 125184; // download
anEvents[1] = 105728; // another way to download
anEvents[2] = 116992; // another way to download
anEvents[3] = 128256; // same folder paste
anEvents[4] = 108544; // new file created
anEvents[5] = 110848; // another way new file created
anEvents[6] = 67584; // file dragged in
anEvents[7] = 127232; // file inside folder that was dragged in
anEvents[8] = 128768; // file replace on paste
```

Please tell me that there has to be a better way? I mean, surely those numbers are the result of some bitwise ANDs on some base number, and then I can do this more scientifically instead of storing some constants?

Comment: The possible values are on that page you linked: [FSEventStreamEventFlags](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/FSEventStreamEventFlags)

Comment: Wow, somehow I missed that! Okay, do you think I should delete this question?

Comment: I think it's simple enough that it might not serve any purpose for other googlers. But, up to you!

Comment: Perhaps I should reword the question so that I can show how to use those flags to determine the bitwise operation? I mean, I'm stuck on figuring that out too.

Comment: Sure. From what you've written so far, I'm not really clear on what you're trying to do. Are you trying to extract or combine flag values?

Comment: I'm working on a real-time connector to a third-party virus scanner API. So, I'm monitoring new file events (in the ways shown above) so that if indeed it's a downloaded file from the web (or the other events shown above), then I can send it to the scanner API for evaluation.